# How would you say "go" as in "Go tell that to the people who survived Vukovar!" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I was wondering, how would you say "*Go tell that to the people who survived Vukovar!*" in Latin? Specifically, how would you translate the word "go" at the beginning of the sentence? Would you say "*Eas id dicere hominibus qui superfuerunt Vukovari!*"? Or "*Eas id dicas hominibus qui superfuerunt Vukovari!*"? Or "*Age id dicere hominibus qui superfuerunt Vukovari!*"? Or "*Age id dic hominibus qui superfuerunt Vukovari!*"? Or maybe something else?

Comment: You don't need the backdrop of denying a massacre to ask this question. Come up with a grammatically comparable situation and ask about it. If the question is about "go" and the surrounding construction, condense the question. For example, ask for a translation of "Water can't hurt you? Go tell that to Noah!". Once you figure that one out, you can easily modify it to any need you may have. Some will find your specific context offending and it certainly takes focus away from your grammatical question.

Comment: FlatAssembler: You asked this question before and it was downvoted and deleted back then. Please refrain from such incendiary revisionism, which is actually against StackExchange's ToC.

Comment: @cmw How is that against the Terms of Service? As far as I know, it's the **genocide** denial that's against the Terms of Service, and no country recognizes Vukovar as genocide.

Comment: @FlatAssembler It falls under the [Misleading Information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct/misleading-information) policy. Note in particular: "Misrepresents, denies, or makes unsubstantiated claims about historical or newsworthy events or the people involved in them."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Go tell" is an English idiom. You don't really get it in Latin, which just uses a simple command.

You can see this with Bowles' famous translation of Simonides' Thermopylae epigram:

> **Go tell** the Spartans, thou who passest by,
> That here, obedient to their laws, we lie.

But in the original Greek, there is no "go", just an infinitive [which can be used in place of an imperative in poetry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0007%3Apart%3D4%3Achapter%3D45%3Asection%3D113%3Asubsection%3D127):

> Ὦ ξεῖν', ἀγγέλλειν Λακεδαιμονίοις ὅτι τῇδε
> κείμεθα, τοῖς κείνων ῥήμασι πειθόμενοι.

There was a Latin translation recorded by Cicero:

> Dic, hospes, Spartae nos te hic vidisse iacentes
> dum sanctis patriae legibus obsequimur.

Again, no sign of "go", just a simple imperative (since Latin cannot substitute the infinitive for an imperative like Greek can).

Also note the change from Λακεδαιμονίοις to Spartae, but since both are dative, the change is immaterial to the grammar.

So, in Latin, "Go tell that to..." is simply *Dic* (or *Dicite* if you're talking to more than one person) plus a dative.

Finally, in Latin, "survivor" is [*superstes, superstitis*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DS%3Aentry+group%3D96%3Aentry%3Dsuperstes), and the plural dative would be *superstitibus*.

Comment: There are several examples in Plautus of *i* + imperative, though the meaning is a bit more literal, e.g. *i adfer X* = "Leave the room and bring X."

Comment: @brianpck I wouldn't be surprised if someone somewhere imitated the Greek use of φέρε and ἄγε in that way, too. Surely at some point the "go" in constructions like "go tell" was also literal, even if isn't always so (compared with "go and do", which is always two commands).

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using *quin* + present indicative to form a 'why not?' question that has the force of an imperative: *quin istud dicis...*, 'Why not tell that...?' (It can also be used with an imperative: *quin istud dic...*.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a great question, and there are probably dozens of different great answers to it. What follows is just my two possible contributions.

"Go tell" is an English idiom, so reaching for a very different Latin idiom, I'd suggest *euntes sic dicite Leutuoani superstitibus*. (Note that I am assuming that *Leutuoanum* is the Latin name of Vukovar; if it isn't, replace it with the correct name.)

A plural participle (like *euntes*) plus a plural imperative (*dicite*) is common enough in Ecclesiastical Latin. If you want a singular version you can swap *euntes/iens*, and *dicite/dic*, although I can't recall ever seeing the participle-imperative combination in the singular. Or you can take a different tack entirely, *ito et sic dicito Leutuoani superstitibus*. "Go and tell...".

Comment: As far as I know, Cornacum was the ancient name for Sotin near Vukovar. The ancient name for Vukovar itself was Leutuoanum.

Comment: @FlatAssembler. Many thanks! I made the change.

Comment: Recently, an example [from this site](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/21978/meaning-of-a-present-participle-in-a-verse-of-vergils-eclogue-8) for singular imperative + participle: *Nāscere, prāēque diem veniēns age, Lūcifer, ālmum*